# Maintain proper symbol order when applying an armature in flash

Tags: animation, flash

I am trying to animate a character's leg in flash CS 5.5 for a game I am working on. I decided to use the bone tool because it's awesome. The problem I am having, however, is that for my character to be animated properly, the symbols that make up his leg (upper leg, lower leg, and shoe) need to be on top of each other in a specific way (otherwise the shoe looks like its next to the leg, etc). Applying the bones results in the following problem: the first symbol I apply it to is placed in the rear on the armature layer, the next on top of it, and so on, until the final symbol is already on top. I need them to be in the opposite order, but arrange > send to back does nothing on the armature layer. How can I fix this?

tl;dr: The bone tool is not maintaining the stacking order of my objects, please help.

Thanks for helping :).

Comment: Don't edit your title to say "solved" - if you really do have a solution, mark it as correct when you can (in ~24 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Modify > Arrange > Send to Back` works, however right clicking and doing an `Arrange > Send to Back` does not. Why this is the case with bones is not yet clear to me, though I think it may have something to do with the right click selecting the entire armature.